# Is a JID a user identifier as well as an application address?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

In the [App Engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#XMPP_Addresses), a JID is defined like this:

> An application can send and receive
>   messages using several kinds of
>   addresses, or "JIDs."

On Wikipedia, however, a JID is defined like this:

> Every user on the (XMPP) network has a unique
>   Jabber ID (usually abbreviated as
>   JID).

So, a JID is both a user identifier and an application address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JID is globally unique in that anyone sending an XMPP message as you@domain.com can be you.

However, an App Engine app can send XMPP messages as any number of JIDs.

Your app can send XMPP messages as `your-app-id@appspot.com` or as `foo@your-app-id.appspotchat.com` or as `bar@your-app-id.appspotchat.com` or as `anything@your-app-id.appspotchat.com`.

These IDs are still globally unique and identifying -- anyone sending an XMPP message as `foo@your-app-id.appspotchat.com` can be assumed to be your app.

Comment: Globally unique is a little strong.  Here's the description from the RFC Joe referenced: '''jid  = [ localpart "@" ] domain [ "/" resource ]'''.  It's the /resource part that makes it not globally unique, and on purpose.  A JID isn't like a MAC address.  You need to separate the authentication for a JID to what resources may exist.  If my JID is romeo@example.com, I can have full JIDs with resources of /home, /work, and /mobile, and receive messages sent to romeo@example.com at any or all of the full JIDs.  That's why I wouldn't call the JID unique.  (Identity is a little different.)

Answer (score 0):

Since I happened to have this up in my browser, the current best canonical definition of JIDs is here: [draft-saintandre-xmpp-address](http://xmpp.org/internet-drafts/draft-saintandre-xmpp-address-00.html), which just got pulled out of [RFC3920bis](http://xmpp.org/internet-drafts/draft-ietf-xmpp-3920bis-06.html).